# Css max-width not working as expected in div

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML structure like:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.dots-container-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.dots-container {
  max-width: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 1px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 0.875rem;
  position: relative;
}

.dots-container>ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex !important;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transform: translateX(0);
  align-items: center;
  bottom: unset;
  height: 100%;
}

.dots-container>ul li {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 2.5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dots-container-wrapper">
    <div class="dots-container">
      <ul class="dots">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the div "dots-container" has a property max-width: 55px. But in case the width is less than 55px, I would like to use the real width, however, the div is always 55px. This is a problem because I´m using this in a carousel with dots functionality. When there are 5 pictures, you can see 5 dots aligned in the center, but in case there are fewer pictures, let´s say 2, the div is still 55px and the dots don´t seem to be aligned in the center. See example screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to add `d-flex justify-content-center` class in your dots-container-wrapper

Comment: You might have to assign a "fallback" width to `dots-container`. Have you tried `width: auto` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.dots-container` is displayed as a block. By default a block will always try to fill up the entire width. By making the container `.dots-container-wrapper` display flex, it's children will only take up as much space as they need (while also centering them if needed).

```
.dots-container-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; // change to flex
}

.dots-container {
    max-width: 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 0.875rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Nice detail! Thanks!